# replace blank spaces before first word in string, then remove extra blank spaces

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have strings like:

```
string stuff = "    this    is    something you could    use one day";
```

I am using following function to remove extra blank spaces:

```
private string removeThem(string str) { 
    if (str!= null){
        return  Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " "); 
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

so after applying that function I get:

```
" this is something you could use one day"
```

but I want:

```
"this is something you could use one day"
```

How to do it?

Comment: You can just use trim after doing the regex.replace, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just avoid RegEx entirely - they are almost always hard to maintain. If there is a more direct option I'd use that.

How about this:

```
private string removeThem(string str)
{ 
    return String.Join(" ", (str ?? "").Split(new [] { ' ' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily just run a `Trim()` after running the `Regex.Replace()`:

```
string str = str.Trim();
```

---

But if you want a single regex to remove consecutive spaces *and* trim trailing spaces, you could try this regex:

```
^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)
```

Replace by nothing.

`^\s+` matches all spaces at the beginning of the string;

`\s+$` matches all spaces at the end of the string;

`\s+(?=\s)` will match all consecutive spaces and leave one.